# Synchronise only cards assigned to me

Tags: trello, google-calendar

When I synchronise Google Calendar I see the cards of ALL the members on my board.
I don't want to see their tasks on my Calendar, just mine.

Is there a way to sync only those cards that have been assigned to me?

Comment: Are you asking about Google Calendar syncing with a Trello board?